# What Digital Diaries are available?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want an application which can be used as Diary and Event Notifier with password protection. That application should have to run as autostart one. So what I would like to do is record my daily things in there and it have to notify me when an event came to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at this digital diary

[Lifeograph](http://lifeograph.wikidot.com/)

[image: Lifeograph]

Answer (score 1):

Best option is using Google Calendar. Have all the features you asked for.
In case of offline you have different event notifiers available in the Software Center by default try using those or better merge two or more programs to have the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

RedNotebook , this is also one more application for Ubuntu Dairy. you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install rednotebook
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is one more application in Ubuntu named as  almanah , It can be installed by

`sudo apt-get install almanah`

from Edit-> preferences we can set the password too.